# Playing mp4 video using Phonon

Tags: c++, qt, mp4, phonon

I'm trying to write a very simple video player using QT and Phonon, on Windows. My backend is phonon_ds94. First of all, here is the code when I click on "Play" :

```
if (!this->_files.empty()) {
    QString file = this->_files.front();

    this->_files.pop();

    Phonon::MediaSource _src(file);
    this->ui.videoPlayer->play(_src);
}
```

(Here, file is a std::queue of files to read)

If I want to play a .avi ou .wmv, everything works fine. My video play, it's perfect.

But when I want to play a .mp4 file, nothing happen. The videoPlayer stay black.

I've search on the web and see that there is a BackendCapabilities::availableMimeTypes, so I've try it to be sure that my backend is compatible with mp4 - it's in the list. Here is the list of available mime types:

> application/vnd.ms-wpl application/x-mplayer2 application/x-ms-wmd
>   application/x-ms-wmz audio/3gpp audio/3gpp2 audio/aiff audio/basic
>   audio/mid audio/midi audio/mp3 audio/mp4 audio/mpeg audio/mpegurl
>   audio/mpg audio/vnd.dlna.adts audio/wav audio/x-aiff audio/x-mid
>   audio/x-midi audio/x-mp3 audio/x-mpeg audio/x-mpegurl audio/x-mpg
>   audio/x-ms-wax audio/x-ms-wma audio/x-wav midi/mid unknown video/3gpp
>   video/3gpp2 video/avi **video/mp4** video/mpeg video/mpg video/msvideo
>   video/quicktime video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts video/x-mpeg video/x-mpeg2a
>   video/x-ms-asf video/x-ms-asf-plugin video/x-ms-wm video/x-ms-wmv
>   video/x-ms-wmx video/x-ms-wvx video/x-msvideo vnd.ms.wmhtml

I've also connected the `stateChanged` signal of the `mediaObject` to a slot, and when I try to read my video, there is an error saying that file format is not supported.

How can I have Phonon to support it? Should I install a codec pack, even if mp4 is in my list?

Comment: Can you use vlc to find which audio and video streams are inside the file? people are really liberal with file extensions.

Comment: Could you try installing the K-Lite codec pack? I recall a similar issue where the reported capability was not a DirectShow compatible one.

Comment: I've try installing the K-Lite codec pack, nothing change. But I noticed that the video is H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (according to VLC) and the audio is MPEG AAC Audio. Maybe is this the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem and after trying a number of codec packs, here is the one that worked.

[K Lite Mega Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_Lite_Mega_Codec_Pack.htm)

If you go into the advanced install, you can uncheck the "Tools", "Program" (Windows Media Player Classic), "Shell Extension", and later uncheck the free browser toolbars that come with it, you end up with just the codecs.

Afterwards I have been able to play anything on Windows using the qmediaplayer example program included in the Demos folder of the QtSDK.